# Invariance group of a sum of determinants.

Tags: matrices, group-theory

The determinant is invariant with respect to a similar transformation:

$$
\det A = \det PAP^{-1}
$$

A sum of determinant shares this invariance:

$$
\det A+\det B = \det PAP^{-1}+\det PBP^{-1}
$$

But it also admits additional invariances. For example, taking our matrices to be matrix representations of the complex numbers $c_1=a_1+ib_1$ and $c_2=a_2+ib_2$, we get:

$$
\det \pmatrix{a_1&-b_1\\b_1&a_1} + \det \pmatrix{a_2&-b_2\\b_2&a_2} = a_1^2+b_1^2+a_2^2+b_2^2=|c_1|^2+|c_2|^2
$$

Clearly that sum is also invariant with respect to $U(2)$.

---

In the general case, we have:

$$
\det \pmatrix{a&b\\c&d} + \det \pmatrix{e&f\\g&h}=(ad-bc)+(eh-fg)
$$

Clearly the general case must be a super-group of $U(2)$, but what it is exactly?

---

edit:

Suppose we have a function that takes a vector of matrices and outputs a real. We note said vector as follows: $\mathbf{a}:=(\mathbf{A}_1, \mathbf{A}_2, \dots, \mathbf{A}_n)$

$$
f(\mathbf{a}) = \det \mathbf{A}_1+\det \mathbf{A}_2 + \dots + \det \mathbf{A}_n
$$

We now ask for the group of transformations that leave $f(T\mathbf{a})=f(\mathbf{a})$ invariant.

Let take a sum of two terms. We have:

$$
T=\pmatrix{\mathbf{T}_{00} & \mathbf{T}_{01}\\ \mathbf{T}_{10}& \mathbf{T}_{11}}
$$

and

$$
T\mathbf{a} = \pmatrix{\mathbf{T}_{00} & \mathbf{T}_{01}\\ \mathbf{T}_{10}& \mathbf{T}_{11}} \pmatrix{\mathbf{A}_1 \\ \mathbf{A}_2} = \pmatrix{\mathbf{T}_{00} \mathbf{A}_1 + \mathbf{T}_{01}\mathbf{A}_2 \\ \mathbf{T}_{10} \mathbf{A}_1 + \mathbf{T}_{11} \mathbf{A}_2} 
$$

Then

$$
f(T\mathbf{a})= \det(\mathbf{T}_{00} \mathbf{A}_1 + \mathbf{T}_{01}\mathbf{A}_2) + \det (\mathbf{T}_{10} \mathbf{A}_1 + \mathbf{T}_{11} \mathbf{A}_2)
$$

It would stand to reason that the elements of $T$ are of the same class as those of $\mathbf{a}$ (to allow the multiplication). Therefore, the elements are matrices.

I tried solve this with Mathematica but it is a bit ridiculous. Can anyone help?

$$
A1b A1c T00b T00c - A1a A1d T00b T00c - A1b A1c T00a T00d + 
 A1a A1d T00a T00d + A1b A2a T00c T01a - A1a A2b T00c T01a + 
 A1d A2a T00d T01a - A1c A2b T00d T01a + A1b A2c T00c T01b - 
 A1a A2d T00c T01b + A1d A2c T00d T01b - A1c A2d T00d T01b - 
 A1b A2a T00a T01c + A1a A2b T00a T01c - A1d A2a T00b T01c + 
 A1c A2b T00b T01c + A2b A2c T01b T01c - A2a A2d T01b T01c - 
 A1b A2c T00a T01d + A1a A2d T00a T01d - A1d A2c T00b T01d + 
 A1c A2d T00b T01d - A2b A2c T01a T01d + A2a A2d T01a T01d + 
 A1b A1c T10b T10c - A1a A1d T10b T10c - A1b A1c T10a T10d + 
 A1a A1d T10a T10d + A1b A2a T10c T11a - A1a A2b T10c T11a + 
 A1d A2a T10d T11a - A1c A2b T10d T11a + A1b A2c T10c T11b - 
 A1a A2d T10c T11b + A1d A2c T10d T11b - A1c A2d T10d T11b - 
 A1b A2a T10a T11c + A1a A2b T10a T11c - A1d A2a T10b T11c + 
 A1c A2b T10b T11c + A2b A2c T11b T11c - A2a A2d T11b T11c - 
 A1b A2c T10a T11d + A1a A2d T10a T11d - A1d A2c T10b T11d + 
 A1c A2d T10b T11d - A2b A2c T11a T11d + A2a A2d T11a T11d
$$

Comment: The determinant of ${\bf A}$ is the (signed) factor by which ${\bf A}$ "changes the volume of the unit cube" in the vector space.  Thus, any other transformation ${\bf T}$ that "preserves the volume" (i.e., has determinant 1) will give the following invariance:
$$
\det( {\bf A} {\bf T}) = \det(  {\bf T} {\bf A}) = \det( {\bf A} ).
$$
Thus, if ${\bf T} {\bf a} = (   {\bf A}_1 {\bf T}, {\bf A}_2 {\bf T}, \ldots )$, or if this multiplication by ${\bf T}$ is instead on the left, then you will have $f({\bf T} {\bf a}) = f({\bf a})$.  But this is a very strong condition.

Comment: The sum
$$
\sum_{k} \det({\bf A}_{k})
$$
can be thought as the sum of the volumes of the images of the unit cube under the ${\bf A}_{k}$'s.  So, any transformation of the whole "vector" ${\bf a}$ that preserves that sum (i.e., if increasing some of the volumes, decreases the other by a corresponding factor), then the sum of the volumes will be preserved.  For example, if $g^t$ is a one-parameter group acting on ${\bf a}$ ("somehow, I know not how":), then you want:
$$
{d \over dt} f (g^t {\bf a}) = 0.
$$

Comment: Think of the ${\bf A}_{k}$ as a bunch of water tanks, and of $g^{t}$ as a system of interconnecting hoses with pumps that doesn't add any water to the system and doesn't drain any water from the system.

Comment: @avs If we consider U(n) to be the complex version of O(n), can we by analogy then consider the sum of determinants to be the general linear version of O(n)?

Comment: Not sure what you have in mind.  The requirement that each summand determinant is preserved already narrows us down to $SU(n)$.  I may be misunderstanding your plan.

Comment: @avs U(n) is a special case of the sum of det so I believe it cannot be just SU(n). I think each summand determinant need not be preserved, because some determinants can be reduced to zero as long as that which is taken from them is added to the other determinants in the right proportion by the transformation T. The value of the determinants need be preserved only in the special case where there is no transfer of 'mass' between the determinants.

Comment: @avs I guess what I am saying is that for there to be a transfer of mass between the determinants, each matrix $\mathbf{A}_1, \mathbf{A}_2,...$ must be transformed by an operation that scales it - hence it cannot be the 'special' version of the group.